# Unwanted blinking effect on button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to show a **clickable button** over the mouse cursor, whenever the user hover's over an image.

Code I am using: [codepen](https://codepen.io/J0SAL/pen/QWBLGbN)

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");

function movebox(e) {
  box.style.left = event.clientX - 20 + 'px';
  box.style.top = event.clientY - 20 + 'px';
  box.style.display = 'block';
}

function removebox() {
  box.style.display = 'none';
}

function click() {
  console.log("clicked")
}
```

```css
#maindiv {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#maindiv img {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><div id="maindiv">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563884993747-a52423c68196?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1374&q=80" onmousemove="movebox(event)" onmouseout="removebox()" />
  <button id="box" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="click()">click</button>
</div>
```

**Problems**:
Getting unwanted blinking effect on button.

I have tried using the `pointer-events: none` property on button, but it also disables the `onclick` events.

Comment: So add a hover to the button to keep it viisble.

Comment: FYI Your code does not account for scroll position of the page.

Comment: @epascarello I tried adding hover effects but still it didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function can not be named "click" because when you call it you are calling the built in click method.

Updated your code to rely on CSS to show and hide the element. Added hove to the img and the button.

Fixed a bug where you did not account for scroll position.

```js
const box = document.getElementById("box");

function movebox(e) {
  box.style.left = window.scrollX + event.clientX - 20 + 'px';
  box.style.top = window.scrollY +  event.clientY - 20 + 'px';
}

function clickMe() {
  console.log("clicked")
}
```

```css
#maindiv {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  padding: 1px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#maindiv img {
  max-width: 400px;
  max-height: 400px;
  object-fit: scale-down;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

#box {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  display: none;
  transition: all .25s;
}

#maindiv img:hover + #box,
#box:hover
 {
display: block;
}
```

```html
<!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cuYeSxntonz0PPNlHhBs68uyIAVpIIOZZ5JqeqvYYIcEL727kskC66kF92t6Xl2V" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script><div id="maindiv">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1563884993747-a52423c68196?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1374&q=80" onmousemove="movebox(event)" />
  <button id="box" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="clickMe()">click</button>
</div>
```